# Problem Solving Differential Equation Initial Value Problem Symbolically

Tags: matlab

I need to evaluate

```
dsolve('Dy = 1 + exp(y)', 'y(0) = 1', 't')
```

symbolically to conclude that

```
t* >= log(exp(1) + 1) - 1.
```

However, when I run it, I get a warning saying it can't be solved explicitly and throws an [empty sym].

Similar equations don't seem to have this problem. Anyone have any ideas as to why it's not evaluating?

Comment: Where did you get that "conclusion"?  What makes you think that it's correct?  Perhaps the warning is telling you to check your assumpions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that Wolfram Alpha [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%20=%201%20%2b%20e%5Ey):

Use that to calibrate your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

very unstable equation.... as an alternative, you can do:

```
e = exp(1);
yfun = dsolve('Dy = 1 + e^y', 'y(0) = 1', 't');
t = 0:0.01:0.3;
eval(yfun);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same problem with this.

Comment: which version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Oh okay, once you changed the first line it worked, but do you know if there's a way to substitute exp(1) back into e so it will cancel with extraneous terms? Here was my result: `log(-e^(t + log(e/(e + 1))/log(e))/(e^(t + log(e/(e + 1))/log(e)) - 1))/log(e)`

Comment: use eval after defining t as shown above or syms... like I said... very unstable... it blows up with t > 0.31